# Embarking a ship on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, travel

Ignoring questions of carrying, activating electronic devices, etc. (assuming these can be overcome), why is it not permissible to embark on a ship which is manned by non-Jews and which will sail on shabbat?

Is it any different from getting on a bus being operated by a non-Jewish driver, to whom one has handed one's ticket before Shabbat (which I think is permissible - again, ignoring *marit ayin*)?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Peter and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 4):

[DailyHalacha](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1594) provides one reason that embarking on a boat is different from boarding a bus which is that you get sea-sick on many boats - not on buses. Since they provide one minority opinion which differs, it is a question best answered [by your rav](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

> Hazal enacted this prohibition forbidding boarding a ship within a few
>   days of Shabbat because doing so will likely interfere with one's
>   "Oneg Shabbat" – the enjoyment of Shabbat. It often takes several days
>   to accustom oneself to sea travel and overcome seasickness, and so the
>   Sages forbade boarding a ship too close to Shabbat in order to ensure
>   that one will be comfortable and at ease on Shabbat.
>
> Interestingly, Rabbi Moshe Halevi (Israel, 1961-2001), in his work
>   Menuhat Ahava (1:2), raises the possibility that this enactment of
>   Hazal might not apply nowadays, when boats are very large and stable.
>   Furthermore, most people who travel on cruises are accustomed to sea
>   travel and thus do not become seasick. Nevertheless, the vast majority
>   of Halachic authorities dispute this position and forbid boarding a
>   ship after Tuesday (or Wednesday), unless one travels for the purpose
>   of performing a Misva.

See [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=3218) for more details and the views of the Rif and Rambam - aligned with the above.

Comment: Doesn't your answer refer to embarking a ship close to Shabbat, while the question asks about sailing on Shabbat in general? (Besides misleading title of course.)

Comment: First para also speaks on embarking on a ship and second para on getting on a bus. So I think I got it right but happy to get corrected if needed

Comment: Are you saying it's permitted to board a bus on Shabbos because you don't get see sick? How about Motion sickness and *Uvda dechol*? I'm sorry but no Rabbi would permit without *Tzorech Mitzvah*

Comment: @yosefkorn I think you are misunderstanding what I wrote. Nowhere do I speak of buses, it is the OP who makes the point that buses might be allowed. I disagree (for your reasons and more) but in any case my answer only adresses boats.

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna Brura Orach Chaim 248 which discusses all of the questioners problems.

> והנה המחבר אף שנמשך בס"ב אחר הרי"ף שהעתיק פירושו מ"מ גם הוא ס"ל כהפוסקים דקודם ג' ימים שרי אף במקום שיצטרך אח"כ לבוא לידי חילול שבת ע"י מלאכה וכמ"ש ס"ד [ועיין במה שכתבנו שם] אלא דס"ל דאף אי לא היה בו שום חשש מלאכה ותחומין [כגון שהיא כולה של א"י דכשנעשה בה מלאכה מסתמא אדעתיה דא"י נעשה וגם היא במקום שעמוק יותר מעשרה טפחים דאין בזה משום איסור תחומין להרבה פוסקים וכדלקמן בסימן ת"ד ע"ש] אפ"ה אסור משום ביטול עונג שבת לחוד
>
> The Shulchan Aruch holds that one can travel more than 3 days before Shabbos on a boat even though he might be forced to save his life by doing a Melacha as he is used to the rocking of the boat.
>   However from Wednesday onward one cannot travel on a boat (unless for the sake of a Mitzva) because he is distressed by the jerking of the boat.
>   Even though
>   1. There is no issue of Techumin (travelling 2000 amos beyond city borders) when the water is 10 tefachim below the shore
>   2. There is no issue of amira leakum (getile performig a melacha on a Jews behalf) when there is a majority gentile passengers on the boat.
>    One must be relaxed on shabbos (Oneg Shabbos) that one feels strained when on a boat (it sways about, one is nervous it might sink in a storm).

These  3 potential issues mentioned apply when travelling on a bus not for the sake of a Mitzva (see Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 248,1):

1. one is not relaxed (which lurches forward and one is not settled when travelling).
2. One could be travelling out of the *techum* of city which is completely forbidden.
3. the gentile is doing a melacha directly for a Jew if he stops at a bus stop for the Jew to get off(unless most people getting off are Gentiles.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers touched on this, but let me just spell it out more -- even if I'm not combusting anything, doing anything electronic, or carrying anything, there is a prohibition called *Techum Shabbos* -- (lit. "the domain"). I am prohibited from walking ~1 mile past the limits of the city where I was located on Friday night. If you are a good walker and/or live near the edge of your city, you could violate *Techum* just by walking a lot!

So a bus all over Brooklyn would remain within the city limits and thus (in and of itself) within *Techum*. (A Greyhound bus from St. Louis to Chicago, on the other hand, would violate *Techum.*) Embarking on almost any ship is bound to violate *Techum*, unless it is staying very, very close to the shoreline of an inhabited area the whole time (e.g. a yacht circumnavigating Manhattan).

(For this reason, if a ship was far out from land at dusk on Friday, then arrives into port *on* Shabbos morning, the "home city" of the passengers is now the ship, and they are prohibited from disembarking on Shabbos as that also would be a case of breaking *Techum*.)

There are other issues, as other answers referenced -- seasickness; the likelihood someone would need to save your life if something went wrong -- but the clear difference between bus and boat (in most cases) is *Techum.*